# Jquery Bootgrid table row color based on condition

Tags: css, jquery-bootgrid

i would like to change row color based on my condition.
I am using Bootgrid js (http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation)

Here is example:

- my condition can be 1 or 0
- if it´s 1 than I need red background color, if 0 - default

This works on "normal" tables

```
<?php 
if(condition = 1){
  <tr class="red">
} else {
  <tr>
}
?>
```

I have tried with
template formater but it apply on whole table not on my condition

Does anybody know is this possible and how to do this?
Thx

Comment: please share all of codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it with 2 methods

1) shorted if statement like below

```
<tr <?PHP echo ($condition == 1 ? 'class="red"' : ''); ?>>
```

2) Normal if statement

```
<?php 
   if(condition == 1){
     <tr class="red">
   } else {
     <tr>
   }
?>
```

Another way

```
$a_json_row["status"] = 0; // success row
$a_json_row["status"] = 1; // info row
$a_json_row["status"] = 2; // warning row
$a_json_row["status"] = 3; // error row
```

the below js code extend the status mappings.

```
$("#grid").bootgrid({
    statusMappings: {
        4: "wrong"
    }
});
```

Comment: I have found an answer. Its integrated in Bootgrid so I have to use <th data-column-id="status" data-type="numeric" data-visible="false">Status</th> and for each number what you have in your tempalte Bootgrid use different background color (1-success 2 warning, 3 danger...)